# Array de Datas do Ano

Tags: javascript, data

Em JavaScript, como trabalhar com um periodo abrangendo dia, mes e ano ao mesmo tempo e de uma so vez ao inves de usar o New Date() obtendo dia, mes e ano individualmente e criando regras?

A ideia é trabalhar com uma faixa de datas para fazer uma determinada tarefa, sem formulas de ano bissexto, se o dia tem 30 ou 31 dias, etc.

Se conseguirmos armazenar todos os dias do ano em um array fica facil dizer que quero que uma determinada massa de dados deva abranger data-3 e data+7 mais facilmente, por exemplo.

Vi que tem como declarar uma data assim:

`var data = new Date(year,month,date);`

Mas nao funciona como uma variavel dinamica que se possa trabalhar em uma faixa de dias relacionados ao mes e ao ano.

Exemplo: Qual data vem antes de 01/09/2017? Se eu usar data-1 ele saberia que o dia anterior seria 31/08/2017, e assim por diante.

Isso é possivel?

Comment: Podes usar new Date(2010, 1, 0) e vais ter o ultimo dia de janeiro, e usando new Date(2010, 1, -1) vai dar o dia anterior, ou seja 30 de janeiro. Isso näo serve?

Comment: @sergio Interessante, mas preciso trabalhar com base no dia corrente. Pensei em algo assim. var dataAntes = new Date()-4;      var dataDepois = new Date()+3; Acho que vai dar certo.

Answer (score 1):

O construtor `new Date` permite numeros maiores e menores que datas "válidas". Assim podes sempre partir de um dado dia e ir para a frente ou para trás.

Exemplo:

```js
function dateToString(d) {
  return [d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, d.getDate()].map(d => d > 9 ? d : '0' + d).join('-');
}

var hoje = new Date();
var ano = hoje.getFullYear();
var mes = hoje.getMonth();
var dia = hoje.getDate();
for (var i = -10; i < 10; i++) {
  var outroDia = new Date(ano, mes, dia + i);
  console.log(dateToString(outroDia));
}
```

Isso vai imprimir (a partir de hoje):

```
2017-08-22
2017-08-23
2017-08-24
2017-08-25
2017-08-26
2017-08-27
2017-08-28
2017-08-29
2017-08-30
2017-08-31
2017-09-01
2017-09-02
2017-09-03
2017-09-04
2017-09-05
2017-09-06
2017-09-07
2017-09-08
2017-09-09
2017-09-10
```

Comment: Brilhante!!! Grato!!